# How to calculate the following limits?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, limits-without-lhopital

How is it possible calculate the following limits?

$\displaystyle \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\arctan x -x}{x^3}$

$\displaystyle \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\ln(1+x)-x}{x^2}$

$\displaystyle \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sinh x -x}{x^3}$

$\displaystyle \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\cosh x -1}{x^2}$

I have calculated them using L'Hospital's rule.

For example:

$\displaystyle \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\cosh x -1}{x^2}=$

$\displaystyle =\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sinh x}{2x}=$

$\displaystyle =\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\cosh x}{2}=$

$=\displaystyle \frac{1}{2}$

But how is it possible to calculate them without using L'Hospital's rule nor Maclaurin series?

Comment: Is there a reason why you're insisting on calculating it by possibly much more complicated ways?

Comment: Maclaurin series are in my opinion the best way to get this done, why looking for something else?

Comment: I do not want to use Maclaurin series nor L'Hôpital's rule because I think they are just handy shortcuts to obtain a result effortlessly.

Answer (score 0):

Hint : Try using [Taylor series expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#List_of_Maclaurin_series_of_some_common_functions) to appropriate order in $x_{0} = 0$, aka Maclaurin series.

Comment: Jacopo, I have just done it but I want to evaluate that limits without using Maclaurin series nor L'Hôpital's rule.

Comment: @Angelo I mean, an always possible way is to try with notable limits, but it's just hiding under the radar the notable expansion of Taylor's series in my opinion.

Comment: Jacopo, which notable limits could I use ?

Comment: Take a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_limits#Notable_special_limits)

Comment: Jacopo, I have just tried with notable limits but I do not manage to evaluate my limits anyway.